# How to detect iPhone X home indicator?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-x

The new iPhone X has gotten rid of the home button and replaced it with a "home indicator" at the very bottom that allows the user to swipe up to get back to the home screen.

My question is, how do we detect if this home indicator is on the screen? I want to do something like:

```
if (!notfullScreen)
{
    if (swipeBarExists)
    {
        viewHeight -= swipeBarHeight;
    }
}
```

I checked in `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` and found nothing. Basically I don't really know what to call this thing and am having trouble finding an answer.

Comment: Have a look at safeAreaInsets, which encompass the space taken by this area of the screen

Comment: Apple seem pretty clear that we shouldn't be writing code like this. Have a watch of https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/801/

Comment: @Ser Pounce I have not work on this but below link might be useful https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/iphone-x-dealing-with-home-indicator-2e8e47f5647f

Comment: Yeah I realize maybe they want this done differently now but just looking for a quick solution I can place on top of my current code.

Answer (score 14):

You can utilize `safeAreaInsets.bottom`, defined for `UIView` to get the amount of space you should inset your content to ensure it doesn’t underlap the home indicator (or other elements). Note that this value may change, for example, when you rotate to landscape on iPhone it shrinks. To be notified when this occurs, implement `safeAreaInsetsDidChange` in your view controller. You can also utilize the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` with Auto Layout.

So, if you have a full screen view, you could check like so:

```
override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    super.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()

    if view.safeAreaInsets.bottom > 0 {
        //home indicator
    } else {
       //no home indicator
    }
}
```

Note that there is no API to get the height of just the home indicator bar itself.

Comment: I found the safe area to be way too big - and makes your app look like an emulated iOS 10 app.  It actually removes all room after the bevel starts on top and bottom.  I used the old-fashioned way of detecting iPhone X and left a bit of room at the bottom for the indicator.  It isn't awesome, but it works for me and keeps my app looking modern and allows me to override it when I am not on iPhone X.

Comment: Appreciate the response, but revisiting this, this gives you the safeAreaInsets.bottom, but not the height of home indicator. The safeAreaInsets.bottom could include tab bars, toolbars, or any other such thing Apple decides to add in the future.